# How to get the inserted id and potentially the other generated values when using Create with a map

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to make some flexible CRUD functions using GORM and passing the values via a `map[string]any`.

The query is built properly with the following code:

`db.Table(model.TableName()).Clauses(clause.Returning{ Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "id"}}, }).Create(theMap)`

But the question is... how do I get the value of id back into Go? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NVM I found the solution...

`db.Table(model.TableName()).Clauses(clause.Returning{}).Create(theMap)`

The above query will load all columns back to the map.